# react-navigation slows while debugging remotely after updating React-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am developping an react-native mobile application which will be mainly used in android platform. I recently needed to upgrade react native version for react-native-firebase. React-native version was `0.57.2`. I upgraded onto `0.59.6` using [rn-diff-purge](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge). While doing so, I needed to update react-navigation version from `2.17.0` to `3.8.1` (but type version is `@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.23"` as you can see, I don't know if that makes a difference)

After upgrading, only headache was again react-navigation. I solved some issues. But after all, when I enable debug-js remotely, navigation transitions become extremely slow. Especially `this.props.navigation.goBack();` calls. I tried giving name of the component like `this.props.navigation.navigate("SomeRouter");`, but issue is about components' being already mounted, I guess.

Why is this the case? What can be the reason of slowing? How can I debug this? By the way, when debug js remotely is disabled, there is no problem, When debug js remotely enabled, transitions become a disaster!

Here is an example component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BackHandler, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Image from "react-native-scalable-image";
import { NavigationScreenProp, NavigationState } from "react-navigation";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import MenuButton from "../components/MenuButton";
import * as types from "../store/types";



interface IProp {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState>;
}
interface ReduxProps {
  currentUser?: types.User;
  currentCompany?: types.Company;
  currentStore?: types.Store;
}
class Menu extends Component<IProp & ReduxProps> {
  state = {
    UserPermissions: this.props.currentUser.permissions,
    CompanyNo: this.props.currentCompany.SIRKETNO,
    StoreNo: this.props.currentStore.BIRIMNO,

    buttonCount: -1 as number,
    buttonNames: [] as string[]
  };

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "OliMobile",
    headerStyle: { marginTop: 0, backgroundColor: "#fff" },
    headerLeft: null,
    gesturesEnabled: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);


  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
  }

  handleBackButton = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
    return true;
  };

  render() {
    //console.log(this.renderButtonViews())
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", marginTop: -50 }}>
          <Image
            width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // height will be calculated automatically
            source={require("../../img/OliMobile_logo.jpg")}
          />
          {this.renderButtonViews()}
        </View>

        <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "rgb(5, 128, 198)",
              color: "white",
              fontSize: 15
            }}
          >
            Sicil No: {this.props.currentUser.sicilNo} Lokasyon No:{" "}
            {this.props.currentStore.BIRIMNO}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: types.GlobalState) => ({
  currentUser: state.User,
  currentCompany: state.CurrentCompany,
  currentStore: state.CurrentStore
});
export default connect<{}, {}, ReduxProps>(mapStateToProps)(Menu);
```

Here is the App.tsx:

```
/**
 * OliMobile Source Code
 *
 *
 * @author Hayri Durmaz
 * @author Arda Tümay
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PermissionsAndroid, Platform, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import Firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import AKTIVASYON from "./screens/Aktivasyon";
import ChooseStore from "./screens/ChooseStore";
import FIRMAIRSLOKSELECTION from "./screens/firmaIrsaliyeleri/FIRMAIRSLOKSELECTION";
import FirmaIrsMalKabul from "./screens/firmaIrsaliyeleri/FirmaIrsMalKabul";
import FirmaIrsSiparisSelection from "./screens/firmaIrsaliyeleri/FirmaIrsSiparisSelection";
import HareketTipiSelection from "./screens/firmaIrsaliyeleri/HareketTipiSelection";
import IRSLOKSC from "./screens/irsaliyeLokasyon/cıkıs/IRSLOKSC";
import LOKASYONSELECTION from "./screens/irsaliyeLokasyon/cıkıs/LOKASYONSELECTION";
import SEVK from "./screens/irsaliyeLokasyon/cıkıs/SEVK";
import IRSLOKSG from "./screens/irsaliyeLokasyon/giris/IRSLOKSG";
import LOKASYONSELECTIONG from "./screens/irsaliyeLokasyon/giris/LOKASYONSELECTIONG";
import MALKABUL from "./screens/irsaliyeLokasyon/giris/MALKABUL";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import Menu from "./screens/Menu";
import NOTIMPLEMENTED from "./screens/NOTIMPLEMENTED";
import SAYIM from "./screens/sayim/SAYIM";
import SAYIMKAYDET from "./screens/sayim/SAYIMKAYDET";
import SAYIMLOCATIONSELECTION from "./screens/sayim/SAYIMLOCATIONSELECTION";
import NORMALSIPARIS from "./screens/siparis/normalSiparis/NORMALSIPARIS";
import NSDESTINATIONSELECTION from "./screens/siparis/normalSiparis/NSDESTINATIONSELECTION";
import URUNSELECTION, {
  Spinner
} from "./screens/siparis/normalSiparis/URUNSELECTION";
import SABLONSIPARIS from "./screens/siparis/sablonSiparis/SABLONSIPARIS";
import SABLONSIPARISDETAY from "./screens/siparis/sablonSiparis/SABLONSIPARISDETAY";
import URETIMKATEGORISELECTION from "./screens/uretim/siparisliUretim/UretimKategoriSelection";
import URETIMKAYDET from "./screens/uretim/siparisliUretim/UretimKaydet";
import UretimUrunSelection from "./screens/uretim/siparisliUretim/UretimUrunSelection";
import SIPSIZURETIMKATEGORISELECTION from "./screens/uretim/siparissizUretim/SIPSIZURETIMKATEGORISELECTION";
import { persistor, store } from "./store";

type Props = {};
const IMEI = require("react-native-imei");

export async function requestLocationPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the location");
      alert("You can use the location");
    } else {
      console.log("location permission denied");
      alert("Location permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  notificationDisplayedListener: any;
  notificationListener: any;
  unsubscribeFromNotificationListener: any;
  async getPermissions() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const permissions = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE
      );
      if (permissions === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) resolve(true);
      else reject(false);
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.unsubscribeFromNotificationListener();
  };

  componentDidMount() {}

  async componentWillMount() {
    Firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic("pushNotificationsGeneral");

    const channel = new Firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      "channelId",
      "Channel Name",
      Firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
    ).setDescription("A natural description of the channel");
    Firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    // the listener returns a function you can use to unsubscribe
    this.unsubscribeFromNotificationListener = Firebase.notifications().onNotification(
      notification => {
        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
          const localNotification = new Firebase.notifications.Notification()
            .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
            .setTitle(notification.title)
            .setSubtitle(notification.subtitle)
            .setBody(notification.body)
            .setData(notification.data)
            .android.setChannelId("channelId") // e.g. the id you chose above
            .android.setSmallIcon("ic_stat_olimobile") // create this icon in Android Studio
            .android.setColor("#449DEF") // you can set a color here
            .android.setPriority(Firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

          Firebase.notifications()
            .displayNotification(localNotification)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        } else if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
          const localNotification = new Firebase.notifications.Notification()
            .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
            .setTitle(notification.title)
            .setSubtitle(notification.subtitle)
            .setBody(notification.body)
            .setData(notification.data)
            .ios.setBadge(notification.ios.badge);

          Firebase.notifications()
            .displayNotification(localNotification)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
      }
    );

    await this.getPermissions().then(sa => {
      console.log(sa);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<Spinner size="large" />} persistor={persistor}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "gray" }}>
            <Application />
          </View>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginRouter: Login,
    ChooseStoreRouter: ChooseStore,
    MenuRouter: Menu,
    SABLONSIPARISRouter: SABLONSIPARIS,
    SABLONSIPARISDETAYRouter: SABLONSIPARISDETAY,
    NORMALSIPARISRouter: NORMALSIPARIS,
    NSDESTINATIONSELECTIONRouter: NSDESTINATIONSELECTION,
    URUNSELECTIONRouter: URUNSELECTION,
    IRSLOKSCRouter: IRSLOKSC,
    LOKASYONSELECTIONRouter: LOKASYONSELECTION,
    SEVKRouter: SEVK,
    IRSLOKSRouter: IRSLOKSG,
    LOKASYONSELECTIONGRouter: LOKASYONSELECTIONG,
    MALKABULRouter: MALKABUL,
    SAYIMRouter: SAYIM,
    SAYIMLOCATIONSELECTIONRouter: SAYIMLOCATIONSELECTION,
    SAYIMKAYDETRouter: SAYIMKAYDET,
    AKTIVASYONRouter: AKTIVASYON,
    URETIMKATEGORISELECTIONRouter: URETIMKATEGORISELECTION,
    URUNKONTROLRouter: NOTIMPLEMENTED,
    IRSFIRMARouter: NOTIMPLEMENTED,
    ETIKETLEMERouter: NOTIMPLEMENTED,
    URETIMURUNSELECTIONRouter: UretimUrunSelection,
    URETIMKAYDETRouter: URETIMKAYDET,
    HareketTipiSelectionRouter: HareketTipiSelection,
    FIRMAIRSLOKSELECTIONRouter: FIRMAIRSLOKSELECTION,
    FirmaIrsSiparisSelectionRouter: FirmaIrsSiparisSelection,
    FirmaIrsMalKabulRouter: FirmaIrsMalKabul,
    SIPSIZURETIMKATEGORISELECTIONRouter: SIPSIZURETIMKATEGORISELECTION
  },
  {
    // headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "LoginRouter",
    initialRouteParams: { showAlert: true },
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(233, 233, 239)",
      opacity: 1
    }
    // transitionConfig: () => ({
    //   transitionSpec: {
    //     duration: 0,
    //     timing: Animated.timing,
    //     easing: Easing.step0
    //   },
    //   swipeEnabled: false,
    //   animationEnabled: false
    // })
  }
);

// const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(RootStack);
const Application = createAppContainer(RootStack);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Here is the old package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Olimobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.23",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.2",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-show": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-imei": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.17.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-xml-parser": "^1.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.1",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.3",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "\\.snap$",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "cacheDirectory": ".jest/cache"
  }
}
```

Here is my new package.json:

```
{
  "name": "olimobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.23",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.59.6",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-show": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-imei": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-xml-parser": "^1.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.3",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.1",
    "@types/react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.3",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "\\.snap$",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "cacheDirectory": ".jest/cache"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with the version 3 of react-navigation, but downgrading react-navigation onto `v2.18.3` resolved the issue.