# Why react navigation not working with remotejs debugging?

Tags: react-native

In my react native application, navigations are not working when I enable remotejs debugging. Without remote js debugger, it's working fine.
What is the reason for the issue?

Comment: What version of react-navigation are you using? Maybe related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786001.

Comment: @hlg Im using react-navigation v 3

Comment: I am also have the same issue